# Python-Eve: Any pre GET hook after Auth?

Tags: python, flask, eve

It seems that `on_pre_GET_<resouce_name>` gets called even before `Auth.authorize()` happens. Is there any hook that can be used after auth and before getting the item/resource?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? Using TokenAuth, the hooks are called after the `check_auth` from auth class in my case.

Comment: I'm using a custom auth class derived from BasicAuth and has auth implemented in authorize function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is an invalid question. For all of the PRE hooks in eve are called after the Auth happens. Here's the Eve's code looks like for GET for item and resource:

In `/eve/methods/get.py`:

```
   23  @ratelimit()
   24  @requires_auth('resource')
   25: @pre_event
   26  def get(resource, **lookup):
   27      """ Retrieves the resource documents ...
   ..
  143  @ratelimit()
  144  @requires_auth('item')
  145: @pre_event
  146  def getitem(resource, **lookup):
  147      """
```

For PRE events, `@pre_event` decorator is also used after `@required_auth` decorator.